# Solve $f(t)=e^t+e^t\int_0^te^{-\tau}f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integral-equations

The question:
$$\begin{equation*} f(t)=e^t+e^t\int_0^te^{-\tau}f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau \end{equation*}.$$

I believe we need to take the Laplace transform of all terms. I am getting stuck with this part:
$$e^t\int_0^te^{-\tau}f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau.$$

I believe we could utilize the convolution theorem

$$\begin{equation*} (f\ast g)(t)=\int_0^tf(\tau)g(t-\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau \end{equation*}$$

but the $e^t$  in front of the integral is causing problems for me.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Notice that the integral is $\int_0^t e^{\tau-t}f(t)\mathrm dt$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Suppose that $f$ is a solution of $$f(t)=e^t+e^t\int_0^te^{-\tau}f(\tau)\,\mathrm d \tau.$$

In one hand, $f(0)=1$. Moreover, if you derivate, you get
\begin{align*}
f'(t)&=e^t+\underbrace{e^t\int_0^t e^{-\tau}f(\tau)\,\mathrm d \tau}_{=f(t)-e^t}+f(t)=2f(t).
\end{align*}

I let you conclude.

Answer (score 3):

You may produce a first-order ODE by differentiating $f$ with the help of Leibniz integral rule, as it is done in Surb's answer, and it turns out to be a quick method. If you really want to use the convolution theorem with Laplace transforms, you can follow the steps described below.

Note that
$$
e^t \int_0^t e^{-\tau}f(\tau) \,\mathrm{d}\tau = \int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau) \,\mathrm{d}\tau,
$$
with $g(t) := e^t$, so that
$$
f(t) = g(t) + (f*g)(t)
$$
and
$$
F(s) = G(s) + F(s)G(s),
$$
thanks to the said convolution theorem, where $G(s) = \mathcal{L}[e^t](s) = \frac{1}{s-1}$, hence
$$
F(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1-G(s)} = \frac{1}{s+2}
$$
and finally
$$
f(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s+2}\right](t) = e^{2t}u(t),
$$
with $u(t)$ the unit step function, which can be dropped in the case where you consider $t \ge 0$ only.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen another solution where the first step was to multiply $e^t$ into the integral, resulting in $f(t)=e^t+\int_0^te^{t-\tau}f(\tau)\,d\tau$. Is this possible because $e^t$ is not a function of $\tau$?

Comment: @user5587  Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Set $g(t)=e^{-t}f(t)$ to get
$$
g(t)=1+\int_0^t g(\tau)\,d\tau.
$$
This means first that $g$ is infinitely often continuously differentiable. Then the integral equation is equivalent to the IVP
$$
g'(t)=g(t),~~~g(0)=1.
$$
This has a well-known solution.